# jQuery wont load

Tags: jquery-plugins

jQuery wont load. I'm a noob. Tried many things, various syntax tweaks. heres how it stands...

Using jQuery on my hard drive, current version jquery-1.7.1 (also tried v1.7.1.min).

have tried to use the following plugins

1) .scrollTo-1.4.2-min
2) .jqDock.min & jquery.jqDock
3) .jtruncate(current) & jquery.jtruncate.pack
Am using IE8 and Chrome to check on local.

Debugging says...

> (jquery-1.7.1.js) invalid character Line 1 (NB: line 1 is just the
>   beginning of the credit info greyed out text  /*! )
>   (jquery.jtruncate.js) jQuery is undefined Line 1 (NB: line 1 is 
>   (function(jQuery){  )   (my page name) Object doesnt support this
>   property or method Code 0 Line 17 Char 5 (NB: line 17 is  $('').jTruncate({  )

My head code...

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Cressida Haughton - Artist Statement and Biography</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Cressida Haughton - Artist Statement and Biography">

    <meta name="keywords" content="Cressida Haughton,Lab Rat Orchestra,installation,contemporary artist,Coventry,Midlands,Cressida,">

<link href="_css/maintest2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="/_js/jquery-1.7.1.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>

<script src="_js/jquery.jtruncate.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>

<script>window.jQuery || document.write("<script src='_js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js'>\x3C/script>")</script> 

<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function(){
        $('<div id="statement" />').jTruncate({
            length: 200,
            minTrail: 0,
            moreText: "[more]",
            lessText: "[less]",
            ellipsisText: "(truncated)",
            moreAni: "fast",
            lessAni: 2000
        });
    });
```

Then theres some java generated by Dreamweaver, (Rollover image/swap image guff), then page specific CSS  (see below) i also have site wide external css sheet.

```
    #statement {
        position:absolute;
        left:285px;
        right: 190px;
        top:130px;
        width: 607px;
        height: 321px;
    }
```

Then html body.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you please post the content of your head tag? Did you import jquery?

Comment: What you also use the MooTools framework that is loaded along with jQuery? Because Mootools jQuery can cause failure at the load.

Comment: Have added head details.

Comment: Am not using Moo tools as far as I am aware, or am I? (blushes)

Comment: I downloaded jquery from the jquery website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have just tried the following and it appears to work ok (Chrome), I am by no means an expert in jQuery but this line

```
$('<div id="statement"/>')
```

does not look write to me, I have commented where I have changed it, look at http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp or more info.

```
<body>
  <head>
   <title>test</title>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"> 
   </script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
     /* jtruncate - should be external js file */
     (function($){$.fn.jTruncate=function(h){var i={length:300,minTrail:20,moreText:"more",lessText:"less",ellipsisText:"...",moreAni:"",lessAni:""};var h=$.extend(i,h);return this.each(function(){obj=$(this);var a=obj.html();if(a.length>h.length+h.minTrail){var b=a.indexOf(' ',h.length);if(b!=-1){var b=a.indexOf(' ',h.length);var c=a.substring(0,b);var d=a.substring(b,a.length-1);obj.html(c+'<span class="truncate_ellipsis">'+h.ellipsisText+'</span>'+'<span class="truncate_more">'+d+'</span>');obj.find('.truncate_more').css("display","none");obj.append('<div class="clearboth">'+'<a href="#" class="truncate_more_link">'+h.moreText+'</a>'+'</div>');var e=$('.truncate_more_link',obj);var f=$('.truncate_more',obj);var g=$('.truncate_ellipsis',obj);e.click(function(){if(e.text()==h.moreText){f.show(h.moreAni);e.text(h.lessText);g.css("display","none")}else{f.hide(h.lessAni);e.text(h.moreText);g.css("display","inline")}return false})}}})}})(jQuery);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- truncatable div element -->
    <div id="statement">
      <p>This is a statement</p>
    </div>  
    <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function(){
          /* changed from $('<div id="statement" />') */
          $('#statement').jTruncate({
              length: 5,
              minTrail: 0,
              moreText: "[more]",
              lessText: "[less]",
              ellipsisText: "(truncated)",
              moreAni: "fast",
              lessAni: 2000
          });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps, merry christmas :-)

Comment: I will try this in a bit! (Naughtily stealing snippets of time to code battle, in between baking batches of mince pies )  Merry Christmas!

Comment: Do I create a brand new jquery file & add my bit of jquery code to it & link it, (meaning I would then have 3 .js files linked to my html file) or do I add the code to the top or bottom of the plugin file?

Comment: Tom, I started with #statement in my jq, but read on a forum to try replacing it with what I have above. Have now gone back to what I had originally & as your suggestion.  Im a bit confused re jTruncate placement. Should I be putting ALL that jq code (under your suggestion) in a seperate file or inside my jTruncate file/ I'm sorry, its all new to me!

Comment: Tom! Thankyou!! I have tried the code you posted and it works! I have still to actually implement it fully on my page, but feel alot more confident now. Thank you so much for your time & effort. All I ended up doing was replacing the jquery source with the google one you suggested, didn't even get around to using the code you placed under the jTruncate 'to do', as I am assuming that it is the jTruncate plugin (?) which I have linked to already. The point is, it's working! Thanks for the Christmas present!!

Comment: @cress hi, yeah I just copied and paste jtruncate into the html file but that would usually be an external file of its own to make it reusable etc. Usually any large amount of script will be in its own .js file, you end up with something like; jquery.js, jtruncate.js (and if you start writing your own scripts you could have a myscripts.js). Each file will have it own script html tag and gets 'included' using the src attribute of the tag. It might be an idea for you to check out w3schools and get some fundamental knowledge of standard js then move onto jquery. Happy coding

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks so much, your a star. Yes, I started my coding journey at w3schools, very helpful and am a regular visiter. By the by, re hosting jq lib, I had read that some people have problems viewing their changes if jq lib is locally hosted, but stubborn as a mule, I wanted to do it all myself -hehe. Well it didnt work (blushes), so have google cdn hosted now. I've just been searching re cdn hosting & found this [http://encosia.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/] may be of use to a good few people. Merry Christmas/Yule type thing

Comment: Oh, that link again [ http://encosia.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/ ]

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

1. Refer or place the jquery sript tag above all the jquery plugin references.
2. Check if jQuery file reference is actually getting loaded in the browser,you can use fiddler or firebug
3. Also refer the javascript file in the order of their dependencies.
4. Place the document.ready script in body tag instead head section.

Comment: This is all the text above my jquery (inc.script type=)

Comment: The jq script tag is top most, will try fiddler in a bit - never used it before though, will try doc. ready in body too...

Comment: re point 4 - When i put the docu ready script in the body tag, should the rest of the jquery script go with it or should ir stay in the head section?