# jQuery wont load

Tags: jquery-plugins

Jquery wont load. I'm a noob, but have persisted, trawled this site & tried many things, permission settings, reloading java on my system & various syntax tweaks, but no joy. About to give up. Here's how it stands...

Using jquery on my hard drive, current version jquery-1.7.1 (also tried v1.7.1.min).

I have tried to use the following plugins - scrollTo-1.4.2-min, jqDock.min & jqDock, jtruncate (current) & jtruncate.pack. None work. I'm using IE8 and Chrome to check on local.

Debugging says...

> (jquery-1.7.1.js) invalid character Line 1 (NB: line 1 is just the
>   beginning of the credit info greyed out text  /*! )
>   (jquery.jtruncate.js) jQuery is undefined Line 1 (NB: line 1 is 
>   (function(jQuery){  )   (my page name) Object doesnt support this
>   property or method Code 0 Line 17 Char 5 (NB: line 17 is  $('').jTruncate({  )

My head code, (after meta's, UTF8 and title)...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('<div id="statement" />').jTruncate({
            length: 200,
            minTrail: 0,
            moreText: "[more]",
            lessText: "[less]",
            ellipsisText: "(truncated)",
            moreAni: "fast",
            lessAni: 2000
        });
    });
```

Then theres some java generated by Dreamweaver, (Rollover image/swap image guff), then page specific CSS  (see below) i also have site wide external css sheet.

```
    #statement {
        position:absolute;
        left:285px;
        right: 190px;
        top:130px;
        width: 607px;
        height: 321px;
    }
```

Then html body.

Can anyone help?  Cress

Comment: Can you show us your `<script src="..."></script>` tags? Also, Java and JavaScript are two very different things.

Comment: Show your full source or create a simplified example HTML page (that you've tested) and show us that.

Comment: Cory, I have posted the full <head> section on other question page.

Comment: Sosukodo, I'm sorry, I'm not sure what to post for you, (I'm embaressed to say). The whole html to /html or specific elements? I also have an external css page, and the jquery's linked. Please find me on the other question page & i will delete this duplicate one. (a foolish noob mistake)

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery wont load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8625415/jquery-wont-load)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('body').append('<div id="statement" />');
        $('#statement').css({
            length: 200,
            minTrail: 0,
            moreText: "[more]",
            lessText: "[less]",
            ellipsisText: "(truncated)",
            moreAni: "fast",
            lessAni: 2000
        });
    });
```

Comment: So I should be using jQuery v 1.4.2 and not v 1.7.1? I thought the most up to date version would be best?