# Truncating Description Text in Magento

Tags: magento, truncate

I am using Magento 1.7.0.2 and I want to truncate texts of long item descriptions.
So, I stumbled upon this: http://www.jeremymartin.name/projects.php?project=jTruncate.

In my page.xml the following scrips are called:

```
<action method="addJs"><script>jquery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js</script </action>
<action method="addJs"><script>jquery.jtruncate.js</script></action>
```

In my view.phtml I added the following line at the top:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function() {  
    $('#maintext').jTruncate();  
}); 
</script>
```

and in my item description I used:

```
<p id="maintext">....text....</p>
```

Firefox tells me that the scripts get loaded, no errors appear and it does not work.
Anyone have any ideas why or an alternative solution? 
Thank you!

Comment: I just test the demo on there site in FF and it seem to work, one thing I notice is that they are using jQuery 1.2.3 (very old), while you are using 1.8.3. Does the demo on there site work for you in FF?

Comment: Also, do you just want to truncate the string or you want to truncate with to the option to view more?

Answer (score 7):

Try

```
Mage::helper('core/string')->truncate($string, $length);
```

See Mage_Core_Helper_String.

Eg.

```
<p id="maintext"><?php echo Mage::helper('core/string')->truncate('text', 2); ?></p>
```

Also see

- [jQuery wont load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8625415/jquery-wont-load)
- https://gist.github.com/charmpitz/4016986

Comment: I copied your code in the beginning of my description... not working.
Or am I supposed to put it in the view.phtml? In this case I really don't know where.

Comment: What file are you referring to as 'my description` are you trying to adding it in the admin?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I mean the Description-field of the product.
For jquery i used the mygento jquery plugin: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/mygento-jquery-library-and-powerful-plugins.html
And the demo site works fine in FF.

Comment: I have not tested it but I think your issue is because you are using a new version of Jquery compareing to 1.2.3. Take a look at my update answer the github repo seem to be only 6 months old, so you may want to do a diff to see if it is the same file or not

Comment: The only issue is that all the older jQuery extensions are not compatible with 1.7. Should I manually install an old version of it or will it mess up Magento?

Comment: Default Magento 1.x do not uses jquery, but it may affect other plugins/code in your magento site that uses jquery

Comment: How can we use the same in Magento2, i don't want to use substr() like function directly, i want to use same kind of thing in Magento2?